# MVC 5 Epplus Excel Found Unreadable Content

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, epplus

I am trying to write some information to an excel file. I can write data in it with using EPPlus. And download the excel file. But when I run and download this file and open, I see this error.

"Excel found unreadable content in filename.xls. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes."

Even if I did not write anything to file, I got this error.
My code in Excel class is:

```
using MaasRaporlari.Models;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;

namespace MaasRaporlari.Controllers
{
    class AyrintiliHarcamaRapor
    {
        public List<AyrintiliHarcamaProgramiVM2> Ayrintili;

        private static int RaporaEklenebilecekIcerikSayısı = 33;

        public string ExcelTemplatePath { get; set; } // = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Content/Xsl/")); //@"C:\test\OdemeEmriBelgesi.xlsx";
        public string ExcelResultPath { get; set; } // = @"C:\test\OdemeEmriSonuc.xlsx";
        public FileStream Save()
        {
            try
            {
                ExcelTemplatePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/AyrintiliHarcamaProgrami.xlsx");
                ExcelResultPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/Harcama.xls");
                var File = new FileInfo(ExcelTemplatePath);
                using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(File))
                {
                    package.Load(new FileStream(ExcelTemplatePath, FileMode.Open));
                    int sheetCount = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)Ayrintili.Count / RaporaEklenebilecekIcerikSayısı);
                    ExcelWorksheet workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
                    List<ExcelWorksheet> workSheets = new List<ExcelWorksheet>();
                    workSheets.Add(workSheet);
                    package.Stream.Position = 0;
                    if (sheetCount >= 2)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < sheetCount - 1; i++)
                        {
                            ExcelWorksheet tempSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(string.Format("Sheet{0}", i + 2), workSheet);
                            workSheets.Add(tempSheet);
                        }
                    }

                    int icerikSayac = 0;
                    foreach (ExcelWorksheet workSheetItem in workSheets)
                    {
                        package.Stream.Position = 0;
                        decimal MiktarToplam1 = 0;
                        decimal MiktarToplam2 = 0;
                        decimal MiktarToplam3 = 0;
                        decimal MiktarToplam4 = 0;
                        decimal MiktarToplam5 = 0;
                        decimal OranToplam1 = 0;
                        decimal OranToplam2 = 0;
                        decimal OranToplam3 = 0;
                        decimal OranToplam4 = 0;
                        decimal OranToplam5 = 0;

                        MiktarToplam Toplam = new MiktarToplam();

                        int rowPointer = 10;

                        for (int i = 0; i < RaporaEklenebilecekIcerikSayısı; i++)
                        {
                            if (icerikSayac < Ayrintili.Count)
                            {
                                var item = Ayrintili[icerikSayac];

                                package.Stream.Position = 0;

                                MiktarToplam5 = item.Miktar1 + item.Miktar2 + item.Miktar3 + item.Miktar4;
                                OranToplam5 = item.Oran1 + item.Oran2 + item.Oran3 + item.Oran4;

                                MiktarToplam1 += item.Miktar1;
                                MiktarToplam2 += item.Miktar2;
                                MiktarToplam3 += item.Miktar3;
                                MiktarToplam4 += item.Miktar4;

                                OranToplam1 += item.Oran1;
                                OranToplam2 += item.Oran2;
                                OranToplam3 += item.Oran3;
                                OranToplam4 += item.Oran4;


                                workSheetItem.Cells["A" + rowPointer.ToString()].Value = item.One;
                                workSheetItem.Cells["B" + rowPointer.ToString()].Value = item.Two;
                                workSheetItem.Cells["C" + rowPointer.ToString()].Value = item.Aciklama;
                                workSheetItem.Cells["D" + rowPointer.ToString()].Value = item.Miktar1;
                                workSheetItem.Cells["F" + rowPointer.ToString()].Value = item.Miktar2;
                                workSheetItem.Cells["H" + rowPointer.ToString()].Value = item.Miktar3;
                                workSheetItem.Cells["J" + rowPointer.ToString()].Value = item.Miktar4;
                                workSheetItem.Cells["E" + rowPointer.ToString()].Value = item.Oran1;
                                workSheetItem.Cells["G" + rowPointer.ToString()].Value = item.Oran2;
                                workSheetItem.Cells["I" + rowPointer.ToString()].Value = item.Oran3;
                                workSheetItem.Cells["K" + rowPointer.ToString()].Value = item.Oran4;
                                workSheetItem.Cells["AC" + rowPointer.ToString()].Value = MiktarToplam5;
                                workSheetItem.Cells["AD" + rowPointer.ToString()].Value = OranToplam5;

                                rowPointer++;
                                icerikSayac++;

                            }
                        }


                        workSheetItem.Cells["D33"].Value = MiktarToplam1;
                        workSheetItem.Cells["E33"].Value = OranToplam1;
                        workSheetItem.Cells["F33"].Value = MiktarToplam2;
                        workSheetItem.Cells["G33"].Value = OranToplam2;
                        workSheetItem.Cells["H33"].Value = MiktarToplam3;
                        workSheetItem.Cells["I33"].Value = OranToplam3;
                        workSheetItem.Cells["J33"].Value = MiktarToplam4;
                        workSheetItem.Cells["K33"].Value = OranToplam4;

                    }
                    using (FileStream outStream = new FileStream(ExcelResultPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        package.Stream.Position = 0;

                        package.SaveAs(outStream);
                        outStream.Position = 0;
                        package.Stream.Dispose();


                        return (outStream);
                    }

                }

            }


            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;

            }
        }
        public class MiktarToplam
        {
            public decimal Toplam { get; set; }

            public MiktarToplam()
            {
                Toplam = 0;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: .xls in the filename suggests an old pre office 2007-file, not the xlsx-format starting with office 2007. As far as I know EPPlus can only handle the newer files (they are essentially zipped xml files) because it uses the Office Open XML format.

Comment: It was xlsx already. I just made it xls. So, even if I change it to xlsx there is no change. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a few quick questions:

Is it necessary to put the file in the ExcelPackage constructor and then load it(package.Load)?

Why do you set package.Stream.Postision = 0 on line 34 and again line 69?

I am doing this in my solution(wb is the workbook):

```
 var ms = new MemoryStream();
 wb.SaveAs(ms);
 ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Have you tried saving to file instead (Just to make sure that everything is working).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My document is 1 MB at most. Most of them are not bigger than 300 KB. I did this change but I got an error
The process cannot access the file 'c:\users\...\Images\Harcama.xlsx' because it is being used by another process.

Answer (score 0):

Epplus is an old tool for Excel. If you look a little, you can see lots of better tools. And you should research carefully. Additionally, you should look to these tool's websites. When was the last commit or update?
NPOI and GemBox one of the best tools. Good luck.